# how can I sync 2 almost identical disk after dd

Tags: dd

Lets say I have `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. 
Before, I run `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=128M`, and it succeeded.

Then after some time, there is update on first disk, and I want to clone it to second disk. But I don't want to run `dd` from beginning, because ... well it takes time. 
Any solution to update on the `/dev/sdb` without dd'ing from start?

UPDATE : the disk actually is ntfs, so rsync is not a solution. Also, I want the second disk to be bootable like the source disk, using rsync would break so many things.

Comment: How can you know which blocks are updated? What is the reason for this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm trying to clone server to server over ssh, but I don't want to shutdown the old server just for dd'ing 1TB data over 100mbps connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`blocksync`](https://github.com/shodanshok/blocksync), [`bdsync`](https://github.com/TargetHolding/bdsync) or even `rsync --inplace --copy-device` (if your `rsync` version supports it) to achieve what you ask.

Be aware that all these methods will read the *entire* source and destination drives, but they will transfer only changed blocks.

Comment: I never know that there is rsync with --copy-device. Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking of a more complex solution. Good thing this works.

Answer (score 1):

I bet [RSync](https://rsync.samba.org/) will do the job perfectly. Actually, you could also have used it to clone your disks at first instead of using `dd`.

Comment: the disk is ntfs. but I want solution to be as general as possible. and I want the destination disk to be bootable like the source disk, and using rsync would make different uuid, broken bootloader and things like that.

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan Got it ;-) You should have said this (and other details you gave in other comments) while asking your question. Can you, please, update your initial question with these constraints ?

Comment: okay, will do. /15char